# SqlDataAdapter.Update not updating

Tags: database, sqldataadapter

(I should say that im fairly new to vb.net)

I'm having a problem overwriting the entries in my database. I think the problem is that SqlDataAdapter.Update isn't overwriting the database properly with the new datatable info that i've created.

As I understand it, it should totally replace the the info in the database with the datatable when i tell it to update... no?

Here's the problem in a nutshell:

Basically, I have a database (.mdf file) with a table in it called 'test'. I've used SqlDataAdapter to make a dataset using 'test'. I have another datatable that I've made from parsing in a csv - it's called 'ToLoad'. I now want to clear the 'test' datatable, copy in all entries from the csv datatable, then save this to the database.

I've debugged all this and it all seems to work ok, except when I use SqlDataAdapter.Update I get an error telling me I cant duplicate the primary key. This is because the old entries aren't being cleared from the database entirely, before the new ones are being entered from the datatable.

I've checked that the test datatable is being actually cleared early on in the code... and it is.
I've checked that the new csv entries are being copied to the 'test' datatable... and they are.

Any help you can give on this would be *really* appreciated

Thanks
Craig

```
'MAKE A NEW SQL CONNECTION
Dim DBConnection As New SqlConnection

'SET THE CONNECTION STRING.
DBConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Project\Members.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

'OPEN THE CONNECTION TO THE DATABASE
DBConnection.Open()

'OPEN AN ADAPTER AND SELECT EVERYTHING FROM THE 'TEST' TABLE
Dim mySqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Test", DBConnection)
Dim mySqlCommandBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter)





Dim DBDataset As DataSet = New DataSet

'FILL THE DATASET WITH THE TEST TABLE  
 mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DBDataset, "Test")

'CLEAR ALL ENTRIES IN THE DATATABLE (SO I CAN FILL IT FROM SCRATCH)
 DBDataset.Tables("test").Clear()





 ''SET UP A LOOP TO ADD EACH RECORD FROM THE CSV DATATABLE TO THE DATABASE DATATABLE

  Dim CSV_row_number As Int16
  CSV_row_number = ds.Tables("toload").Rows.Count


  Dim i As Int16   
  i = 0
       Do Until i = CSV_row_number - 1


            'MAKES TWO NEW DATAROW OBJECTS
            Dim DB_row As DataRow
            Dim CSV_row As DataRow

            'SET THE CSV_ROW OBJECT EQUAL TO ROW(i) OF THE CSV DATATABLE
            CSV_row = ds.Tables("toload").Rows(i)

            DB_row = DBDataset.Tables("test").NewRow()

            'THIS SETS ALL OF THE COLUMNS IN THIS NEW ROW AS EQUAL TO ROW1 IN THE CSV DATATABLE
            DB_row("Name") = CSV_row("Name")
            DB_row("Quality") = CSV_row("Address")
            DBDataset.Tables("test").Rows.Add(DB_row)

            i = i + 1

        Loop



 mySqlDataAdapter.Update(DBDataset.Tables("Test"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this myself after a fair bit of googling and some trial and error. Posting my code in case it's useful for anyone else

Craig

```
 'MAKE A NEW SQL CONNECTION
    Dim DBConnection As New SqlConnection

    'SET THE CONNECTION STRING. YOU GET THIS BY GOING TO SERVER EXPLORER, THEN CLICKING ON THE DATABASE
    'THE CONNECTION STRING IS IN PROPERTIES 
    DBConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\ME\Project\Members.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

    'OPEN THE CONNECTION TO THE DATABASE
    DBConnection.Open()



    'THIS OPENS AN ADAPTER TO THE DATABASE, AND SELECTS EVERYTHING FROM THE 'TEST' TABLE IN THAT DATABASE
    Dim mySqlDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MemberList", DBConnection)
    'THIS LETS US USE SQL ON THE DATATABLE (IT GETS PASSED THE ABOVE SQL STATEMENT)
    Dim mySqlCommandBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(mySqlDataAdapter)


    'THIS MAKES ANOTHER NEW DATASET 
    Dim DBDataset As DataSet = New DataSet


    ''THIS FILLS THAT DATASET WITH THE TEST TABLE (WHICH THE DATA ADAPTOR GRABBED ABOVE) 
    mySqlDataAdapter.FillSchema(DBDataset, SchemaType.Source, "MemberList")
    mySqlDataAdapter.Fill(DBDataset, "MemberList")


    'THIS MAKES A NEW DATATABLE 
    'I THEN MAKE ALL CHANGES NEEDED 

    Dim EDITmembers As DataTable
    EDITmembers = DBDataset.Tables("MemberList")


    ''FIRST, IM GOING TO CLEAR ALL ENTRIES IN THE DATATABLE (SO I CAN FILL IT FROM SCRATCH)

    'COUNT THE NUMBER OF ENTRIES TO CLEAR
    Dim RowsInDB As Integer
    RowsInDB = EDITmembers.Rows.Count()

    'SET UP A LOOP TO CLEAR THEM
    Dim Data_row As DataRow
    Dim k As Integer = 0

    Do Until k = RowsInDB

        Data_row = EDITmembers.Rows(k)

        Data_row.Delete()

        k = k + 1

    Loop

    'ONCE ALL THE ROWS ARE CLEARED, SAVE THE CHANGES BY UPDATING THE ACTUAL DATABASE
    mySqlDataAdapter.Update(DBDataset, "MemberList")





    ''THEN I SET UP A LOOP TO ADD EACH RECORD FROM THE CSV DATATABLE TO THE DATABASE DATATABLE
    ''I FIRST NEED TO KNOW HOW MANY ITERATIONS OF THE LOOP TO DO

    Dim CSV_row_number As Int16
    'COUNT THE NUMBER OF ROWS AND SET THE ABOVE INT EQUAL TO THIS
    CSV_row_number = ToLoad.Rows.Count


    Dim j As Int16   
    j = 0
    Do Until j = CSV_row_number - 1


        'THIS MAKES TWO NEW DATAROW OBJECTS
        Dim DB_row As DataRow
        Dim CSV_row As DataRow

        'THIS SETS THE CSV_ROW OBJECT EQUAL TO THE FIRST ROW OF THE CSV DATATABLE
        CSV_row = ToLoad.Rows(j)


        'THIS SETS DB_ROW EQUAL TO A NEW ROW IN THE DATATABLE MADE FROM THE DATABASE
        DB_row = EDITmembers.NewRow()

        'THIS SETS ALL OF THE COLUMNS IN THIS NEW ROW AS EQUAL TO THE CORRESPONDING ROW IN THE CSV DATATABLE
        DB_row("Contact Name") = CSV_row("Contact Name")
        DB_row("Do not mail") = CSV_row("Do not mail")
        DB_row("Membership Type") = CSV_row("Membership Type")
        DB_row("Street Address") = CSV_row("Street Address")
        DB_row("Supplemental Address 1") = CSV_row("Supplemental Address 1")
        DB_row("Supplemental Address 2") = CSV_row("Supplemental Address 2")
        DB_row("City") = CSV_row("City")
        DB_row("Postal Code") = CSV_row("Postal Code")
        DB_row("Email") = CSV_row("Email")
        DB_row("Phone (primary)") = CSV_row("Phone (primary)")


        EDITmembers.Rows.Add(DB_row)

        j = j + 1

    Loop




   'UPDATE THE DATABASE WITH ALL THE CHANGES
    mySqlDataAdapter.Update(DBDataset, "MemberList")
    MessageBox.Show("done!")
```